# How should I go about storing resources in C

Tags: c, resources, sdl, storage

What system should I use to store resources (Images, SoundEffects etc) in C?

One example would be storing them in a struct type system:

```
struct _Resource {
    struct _Image {
        SDL_Surface *MenuButton;
    } Image;
    struct _SoundEffect {
        Mix_Chunk *MenuButtonSound;
    } SoundEffect;
} Resource;
```

Another example would be storing them in an array:

```
SDL_Surface *Image[5];
Mix_Chunk *SoundEffect[5];
```

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

There are millions of ways of doing it. Asking about what is the best way is not really constructive. You may want to see how others do it (if not re-using those components/libraries to avoid re-inventing a wheel):

- [GTK Resource Files](http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-Resource-Files.html)
- [Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/resources.html)
- [OS X bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle)
- [Windows resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194804.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This question is very general, so here's the general answer:

First, you should know that `struct` an array are orthogonal concepts. You don't need to choose between them, you can have both.

Now usually, when you decide to have a `struct`, it's because the data are somehow related. For example, if you have resource that is clickable and has a position, a struct such as the following

```
typedef struct Resource
{
    int x, y;
    SDL_Surface MenuBotton;
    void (*click_callback)(struct Resource *);
} Resource;
```

makes sense. However, if you have two unrelated concepts, such as image and sound, it absolutely doesn't make sense to put them together in one struct (unless for special cases, such as sending the pointer to a thread!)

So what you need to do is, **divide different concepts and group information that are relevant to each other**. Make structs out of the relevant information and create arrays of them if you have many instances of them.

In the end, you may want to have one big struct containing everything worked on by a manager of some sort, but that certainly depends on your application.